# Unable to run a new created react native project from visual studio Code

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code, sdk

I'm new to react native, and I always work with visual studio 2019. There I worked with Xamarin.
As you know when you download Visual studio and work with xamarin the android SDK is installed in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

for Which the adb is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

So I created a `local.properties` and added `sdk.dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

Then I run my react native project on android.

Also with the addition to the error below where i get `java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`
I also get no emulator found which is very odd because I have all the Emulator installed in the above path.
So i Plugged in my android device instead.

please guide me if this is something that have to do with the android SDK beging installed by visual studio 2019

Debug output

```
[Warning] Target simulator is not supported for Android platform. 
 If you want to use particular device or simulator for launching Android app,
 please specify device id (as in 'adb devices' output) instead.

[Info] Using Android SDK location defined in android/local.properties file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools.

[Info] Starting React Native Packager.

[Info] Attaching to running React Native packager

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1296 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
info Installing the app...
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.

> Configure project :app

�[33mInstalling unimodules:�[0m
 �[32munimodules-core�[33m@�[31m6.0.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\@unimodules\core�[0m
 �[32munimodules-react-native-adapter�[33m@�[31m5.7.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\@unimodules\react-native-adapter�[0m
 �[32mexpo-application�[33m@�[31m2.4.1�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-application�[0m
 �[32mexpo-constants�[33m@�[31m9.3.5�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-constants�[0m
 �[32mexpo-error-recovery�[33m@�[31m1.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-error-recovery�[0m
 �[32mexpo-file-system�[33m@�[31m9.3.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-file-system�[0m
 �[32mexpo-font�[33m@�[31m8.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-font�[0m
 �[32mexpo-image-loader�[33m@�[31m1.3.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-image-loader�[0m
 �[32mexpo-keep-awake�[33m@�[31m8.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-keep-awake�[0m
 �[32mexpo-linear-gradient�[33m@�[31m8.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-linear-gradient�[0m
 �[32mexpo-location�[33m@�[31m10.0.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-location�[0m
 �[32mexpo-permissions�[33m@�[31m10.0.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-permissions�[0m
 �[32mexpo-secure-store�[33m@�[31m9.3.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-secure-store�[0m
 �[32mexpo-splash-screen�[33m@�[31m0.8.1�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-splash-screen�[0m
 �[32mexpo-sqlite�[33m@�[31m8.5.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-sqlite�[0m
 �[32mexpo-updates�[33m@�[31m0.4.1�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\expo-updates�[0m
 �[32munimodules-app-loader�[33m@�[31m1.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-app-loader�[0m
 �[32munimodules-barcode-scanner-interface�[33m@�[31m5.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface�[0m
 �[32munimodules-camera-interface�[33m@�[31m5.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-camera-interface�[0m
 �[32munimodules-constants-interface�[33m@�[31m5.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-constants-interface�[0m
 �[32munimodules-face-detector-interface�[33m@�[31m5.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-face-detector-interface�[0m
 �[32munimodules-file-system-interface�[33m@�[31m5.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-file-system-interface�[0m
 �[32munimodules-font-interface�[33m@�[31m5.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-font-interface�[0m
 �[32munimodules-image-loader-interface�[33m@�[31m5.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-image-loader-interface�[0m
 �[32munimodules-permissions-interface�[33m@�[31m5.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-permissions-interface�[0m
 �[32munimodules-sensors-interface�[33m@�[31m5.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-sensors-interface�[0m
 �[32munimodules-task-manager-interface�[33m@�[31m5.4.0�[0m from �[35mD:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\unimodules-task-manager-interface�[0m

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Projects\NovelLator\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 89

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

And this is My build.grade.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools` I have the 29.0.2 map version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a windows user,

You Have open emulator using android studio or CMD manually.

why is that?

react-native run-android command doesn't start emulator automatically in windows.

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying, Where is the solution too the problem ?

Comment: When you use windows, Emulator don't start automatically so then you have to run emulator manually then after run your react native project